# Error 1004 in Elseif condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that looks like this :

[image: excel sheet]

For each cell, I want to find the latitude and longitude of the row and column header (the "Obj") that are in separate worksheets (1 worksheet per "Obj" type). I've put my code underneath.

At the moment, it works fine for the first row, until it reaches "ObjB1". When I run it in "debug mode", it reaches 
`If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search("ObjA", Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j))) = True Then` before stopping

> Error 1004

without ever going into the "Elseif" condition.

Sub Distances()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Lat1 As Variant
    Dim Lat2 As Variant
    Dim Long1 As Variant
    Dim Long2 As Variant
    Dim Dist As Variant

```
'Going through the empty cells
    For i = 2 To Sheets("Distancier").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To Sheets("Distancier").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' If ObjA is part of the string in the row header (Column A), then lat1 and long1 take the values of the latitude and longitude of the text in the row header

        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1), "ObjA", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsA").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsA").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)
        ' Same here but ObjB is part of the string
        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1), "ObjB", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsB").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsB").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)

        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1), "ObjC", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsC").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsC").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)

        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1), "ObjD", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsD").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("ObjetsD").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)
        Else:
            Lat1 = 0
            Long1 = 0
        End If

        ' This block does the same thing as the first block but looks through the column headers (row 1)
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j), "ObjA", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsA").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsA").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)

        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j), "ObjB", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsB").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsB").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)

        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j), "ObjC", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsC").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsC").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)

        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(InStr(1, Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j), "ObjD", vbTextCompare)) = True Then
            Lat2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsD").Range("A2:P2000"), 3, False)
            Long2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(1, j).Text, Sheets("ObjetsD").Range("A2:P2000"), 4, False)
         Else:
            Lat1 = 0
            Long1 = 0
        End If

        ' If the latitudes and longitudes are numbers, then the distance between the two points is calculated.

        If WorksheetFunction.And(WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Lat1), WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Lat2), WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Long1), WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Long2)) Then
            Dist = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Acos(Sin((3.14 / 180) * Lat1) * Sin((3.14 / 180) * Lat2) + Cos((3.14 / 180) * Lat1) * Cos((3.14 / 180) * Lat2) * Cos((3.14 / 180) * (Long2 - Long1))) * 6371, 0) * 1.3
        End If
        Sheets("Distancier").Range("A1:P20000").Cells(i, j).Value = Dist
    Next
Next
```

End Sub

All the help is welcome as I cannot figure out why it doesn't work !

Thanks.

Comment: You need to look into `Instr()` in vba.

Comment: wadr, whatever you are trying to do I can only see you doing it inefficiently and most likely wrong. Can you expand your narrative sans debris and provide a better description along with some sample data together with expected results? [mcve]

Comment: need to step back and take a look at this.

Comment: I've changed WorksheetFunction.Search to Instr. I'll comment the code in the first post to give you insight on what I had in mind.

Comment: In VBA you can use `ISNUMERIC()` without `Worksheetfunction`, FYI.

Comment: Inst will always return a number.  If not found it will return 0.

Comment: Indeed, by changing the condition to ">0" it works. Thanks.